# file_put_content arrays, but adding just one line

Tags: php

Currently, I'm using this

```
$a = "one line";
$emails = array();
while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    emails[] = $row['id'];
}


file_put_contents("uploads/",$emails, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

And so ofcourse it prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Is it possible to attach **$a** to the top of the print file? Just single line of text instead of arrays.

I basically need it to look like this

```
one line
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: And what is stopping you from calling `file_put_contents` one more time, huh?

Comment: Why not declare an array with that line in the first place? `$emails = ['one line'];`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$emails = "one line\n";
while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $emails .= $row['id']."\n";
}

file_put_contents("uploads/",$emails, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```